# Как сделать Volley синхронным?

Tags: android, jsoup, асинхронность, android-volley

Я пишу на основе парсера андроид-лиент для браузерной игры) Так вот,  Jsoup синхронен, тоесть другой код идущий дальше выполняется когда закончит Jsoup. Но его нельзя использовать в майн потоке приложения и приходится писать `AsyncTask`. Библиотека Volley асинхронна, что неудобно, приходится размещать код после загрузки в `onResponse`, но ее не надо размещать `AsyncTask`. Как убить сразу двух зайцев?

Comment: Добавьте код, как вы делаете асинхронный запрос, чтобы можно было его изменить на синхронный. Либо сами гуглите `RequestFuture`.

Comment: а лучше через `Retrofit` делать, который во много раз гибче